# IP works on server, but not able to connect on local network

Tags: apache-http-server, firewall, ubuntu-18.04, arm

I hae been trying to have an owncloud server on my jetson nano. The installation and setup for the server is done and it works. But for some reason the server is not accessible on my LAN.

When I use the browser on my jetson, it allows me to go to the site `http://<ip-address>` but any other device on the same network is not able to connect to it. This makes me think that it is a firewall issue. I still have been unable to find a solution to this, would love to have some ideas.

I am unable to use ufw due to some [issues](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fix-for-ufw-on-jetpack/202340) present in the jetson os. I have already unsuccessfully tried to add a rule using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But it is all to no avail. I am sure I am missing something small but cannot put a finger on it yet. Do let me know how to debug and/or to solve this problem.

Additional Detials:

- Hardware: Jetson Nano 2GB
- OS: Linux4Tegra (based on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: What kind IP address are you using? Does the server have a public address or a private (10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x, or even 172.16-31.x.x) address, and if it's private are you using that or the router's public address, or ...?

Comment: It is a private IP address @GordonDavisson - 192.168.X.X. And I am using the IP address the router has assigned to my device and not the router's public/private address